# SAP GUI Script - Brief Explaination on .NodeContextMenu

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I have a recorded a script that involving right-clicking a project structure (network/tree?) in CJ20N. The outcome looks like this:

`session.FindById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").NodeContextMenu "000066"`

Currently I don't know how to obtain the reference "000066" manually or via coding.

My intention is to create a macro in VBA and applied it on other project structure (network/tree). However, the recorded script is rigid, hence I appreciate it if the community could advise me on how to obtain the reference "000066" for other project structure (network/tree).

Thanks.

Comment: I was never able to find a way other than interacting with the elements while recording the script. SAP is intentionally poorly documented.